# Solving for 'u' algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I isolate, in $s = ut + 1/2at^2$

'u' ?

I've forgotten how to basic math. I need this for a projectile question. I will mark the correct answer.

Comment: I would say:  $u=\frac{s-1/2at^2}{t}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
s &= ut+\frac 12at^2 \\[2 ex]
ut+\frac 12at^2 &= s \\[2 ex]
ut &= s-\frac 12at^2 \\[2 ex]
u &= \frac{s-\frac 12at^2}{t}\\[2 ex]
u &= \frac st-\frac 12at\\[2 ex]
\end{align}$$

Use either of the last two expressions.

---

Now let's look at the situation where an object falls from rest. Since the object will move in only one direction, down, the distance travelled is the same as the displacement. So we will use the variable $d$ for distance rather than $s$ for displacement. "Falls..." means $a=g$ (the acceleration is that of gravity), and "... from rest" means $u=0$ (zero initial velocity). So using that same equation,

$$\begin{align}
s &= ut+\frac 12at^2 \\[2 ex]
d &= 0\cdot t+\frac 12gt^2 \\[2 ex]
d &= \frac 12gt^2 \\[2 ex]
2d &= gt^2 \\[2 ex]
\frac{2d}g &= t^2 \\[2 ex]
\sqrt{\frac{2d}g} &= t \\[2 ex]
\end{align}$$

There is no need for the plus-or-minus in the last expression, since the time interval is positive.

Comment: legend, thanks !